# File Download error on click of an image link

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to download an excel file on click of an img link in my Angular UI project . I tried

```
<div class="export-template-label" style="display:inline-block;margin:5px 5px -8px 0px;">
    <a download="Group Membership Upload Template.xlsx" href="../Files/Group Membership Upload Template.xlsx" target="_self">
        <img src="Images/excel.png" href="../Files/Group Membership Upload Template.xlsx" alt="logo" style="float:left;" />
    </a>
</div>
```

I want the file that would be downloaded to be named `Group Membership Upload Template.xlsx`

A file with this name already remains in the Files Folder under the parent folder .

But on click of the link it says `Failed - No File`. 
[image]

What needs to be done ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try this code.

```
<div class="export-template-label" style="display:inline-block;margin:5px 5px -8px 0px;">
    <a href="../Files/Group Membership Upload Template.xlsx" target="_self" download>
        <img src="Images/excel.png" alt="logo" style="float:left;" />
    </a>
</div>
```